# purrr mapping more than two variables (for making a pairplot with ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

i enjoy using purrr's map and map2 a lot, but i often find myself in the situation of wanting to map more inputs. I know there is also pmap but i don't really understand how to use it.

Below is my example for creating a pairplot in ggplot2. It is missing the value of name.x as label for the x-axis.

```
plots = iris%>%
  pivot_longer(!Species)%>%
  left_join(
    iris%>%
      pivot_longer(!Species),by="Species"
  )%>%
  group_by(name.x,name.y)%>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(
    plots =
      map2(
        .x=data,.y=name.x,
        ~ggplot(.x)+
          geom_point(aes(value.x,value.y,color=Species))+
          xlab(.y)
  ))

ggarrange(plotlist=plots$plots, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")
```

I'm looking forward to your suggestions!
It would be ideal if they could be used smoothly in a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pmap` like so:

```
plots <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species)%>%
  left_join(iris %>% pivot_longer(!Species), by = "Species")%>%
  group_by(name.x, name.y) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plots = pmap(
    list(data, name.x, name.y),   
    \(d, x, y) ggplot(d)+
      geom_point(aes(value.x, value.y, color = Species))+
      xlab(x) + ylab(y)
  ))
```

That is:

- Collect the variables you want to map over in a list, so `list(data, name.x, name.y)`
- Define a function that takes those arguments.

There's several ways of defining that function. E.g. you could use the formula syntax like you did for `map2`, with `..1`, `..2` and `..3`. But I like the new syntax for anonymous functions (i.e. `\(x, y)`) quite a bit better, since you can name the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the code your shared since name.x and name.y are the same in all rows and hence plots. But here you go:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
plots <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(!Species) %>%
  left_join(
    iris %>%
      pivot_longer(!Species),
    by = "Species", relationship =
      "many-to-many"
  ) %>%
  group_by(name.x, name.y) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    plots =
      pmap(
        list(.x = data, .y = name.x, .z = name.y),
        function(.x, .y, .z) {
          ggplot(.x) +
            geom_point(aes(value.x, value.y, color = Species)) +
            xlab(.y) +
            ylab(.z)
        }
      )
  )

ggarrange(plotlist = plots$plots, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In `pmap` I write out function and then define variable names. The vectors inside the list are then automatically supplied in order.